# Spectral radius of a complete bipartite graph

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, spectral-radius

Let $p, q > 0$ be integers and let $K_{p,q}$ be a complete bipartite graph. Let $A(K)$ denote the adjacency matrix of $K_{p,q}$ according to a convenient labeling of vertices , which is the $2 \times 2$ block matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0_{p \times p} & 1_{p \times q}\\
1_{q \times p} & 0_{q \times q} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I know that the spectral radius of $A(K)$ is $\sqrt{pq}$ but couldn't prove it. I tried to find the determinant of the characteristic polynomial in order to find the spectrum but also couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral radius of $A(K)$ is the square root of the spectral radius of $A(K)^2$. Note that
$$
A(K)^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
q\mathbf{1}_{p \times p} & 0\\
0 & p\mathbf{1}_{q \times q}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence
$$
\det(xI - A(K)^2) = \det(xI - q\mathbf{1}_{p \times p})\det(xI - p\mathbf{1}_{q \times q}) = (x - pq)^2x^{p + q - 2}.
$$

Comment: Define $X$ please.

Comment: @sal.f Sorry, I meant $K$. Edited.

Comment: No worries, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but how did you find $\det(xI - q\mathbf{1}_{p \times p})$ ?

Comment: $pq$ is clearly is an eigenvalue of $q\mathbf{1}_{p \times p}$ (take $\mathbf{1}_{p \times 1}$ as an eigenvector) and this matrix has rank 1, so $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $p - 1$, which implies that $pq$ has multiplicity $1$ and there can be no other eigenvalues.

Comment: Okay , thank you

Comment: One could use the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to compute the characteristic polynomial of each block.