# Spectral radius of a complete tripartite graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-radius, adjacency-matrix

I am reading an article that mentions that it can be checked that $K_{4,4,12}$ and $K_{2,9,9}$ have the same spectral radius, namely, $12$, i.e., according to the corresponding adjacency matrices with a convenient labeling. For example, the adjacency matrix of $K_{4,4,12}$ would be

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0_{4 \times 4} & (1) & (1)\\
(1) & 0_{4 \times 4 } & (1)\\
(1) & (1) & 0_{12 \times 12}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $K_{4,4,12}$ and $K_{2,9,9}$ are complete $3$-partite graphs.
How did they calculate the spectral radius?

Comment: I computed the spectral radii numerically, and they both turn out to be $12$ for what that's worth.

Comment: would you please mention how? and which method did u use

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2738091/339790

Answer (score 1):

The adjacency matrix of the complete tripartite graph $\mathcal K_{4,4,12}$ is the $20 \times 20$ symmetric matrix

$$\mathrm A := \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}}_{=: \mathrm M} \otimes 1_4 1_4^\top = \mathrm M \otimes 1_4 1_4^\top$$

Since $\rm A$ is symmetric, its spectral radius is equal to its spectral norm, i.e.,

$$\rho (\mathrm A) = \| \mathrm A \|_2 = \sigma_{\max} (\mathrm A) = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm A^\top \mathrm A \right)} = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm A^2 \right)}$$

where

$$\mathrm A^2 = \mathrm M^2 \otimes 1_4 \underbrace{1_4^\top 1_4}_{=4} 1_4^\top = \mathrm M^2 \otimes 4 \, 1_4 1_4^\top = 4 \mathrm M^2 \otimes 1_4 1_4^\top$$

and

$$\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm A^2 \right) = 4 \cdot \lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm M^2 \right) \cdot \underbrace{\lambda_{\max} \left( 1_4 1_4^\top \right)}_{= \mbox{tr} \left( 1_4 1_4^\top \right) = 4} = 16 \cdot \lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm M^2 \right)$$

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org),

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> M = Matrix([[0,1,1,1,1],
                [1,0,1,1,1],
                [1,1,0,0,0],
                [1,1,0,0,0],
                [1,1,0,0,0]])
>>> (M**2).eigenvals()
{0: 2, 9: 1, 4: 1, 1: 1}
```

and, thus, $\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm M^2 \right) = 9$. Lastly, the spectral radius of $\rm A$ is

$$\rho (\mathrm A) = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm A^2 \right)} = 4 \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm M^2 \right)} = 4 \sqrt{9} = 12$$

Comment: Sorry, but how did you find the adjacency matrix? I only saw M to be the adjacency matrix, so why is there a direct sum?

Comment: Also,would you please explain why is the spectral radius equal to the spectral norm? How does $A$ being symmetric help? Thank you

Comment: It is not a direct sum, it is a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). For symmetric matrices (which have real eigenvalues), the spectral radius is equal to the spectral norm. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603375/339790).

Comment: $\rm M$ is **not** an adjacency matrix. I viewed $\rm A$ as a $5 \times 5$ block matrix where each block is $4 \times 4$. Then wrote it using the Kronecker product so that I could focus on $5 \times 5$ matrix $\rm M$ instead of on $20 \times 20$ matrix $\rm A$.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the statement, but I have no idea why one would expect it to be true.  I computed the spectral radii numerically with numpy, and they both turn out to be $12$.  I used numpy, and the function `numpy.linalg.eigs` which gives the associated eigenvectors as well as the eigenvalues.  The eigenvectors are returned normalized, but in this case, they were of simple structure, and I was easily able to find eigenvectors with integer components so that I could do exact arithmetic.

Here is my python script for confirming the eigenvectors.  In case you don't know python, A is the adjacency matrix of $K_{4,4,12}$ and B that of $K_{2,9,9}$.   The eigenvector of A is
$$
(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$$
and the eigenvector of B is $$
(3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$$

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((20,20), dtype=int)
A[0:4,0:4]=0
A[4:8,4:8]=0
A[8:20,8:20]=0

x = np.array(8*[3]+12*[2])
y = np.array(20*[0], dtype=int)
z= 12*x-A@x
assert all(y[i]==z[i] for i in range(20))

B=np.ones((20,20), dtype=int)
B[0:2,0:2]=0
B[2:11,2:11]=0
B[11:20,11:20]=0

x = np.array(2*[3]+18*[2])
y = np.array(20*[0], dtype=int)
z= 12*x-B@x
assert all(y[i]==z[i] for i in range(20))
```

We note that the matrixes are irreducible, so the Perron-Frobenius theorem applies.  One of assertions is that the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue is the only one with an associated eigenvector of non-negative elements, which proves that $12$ is the maximum eigenvalue in both cases.

**EDIT** On second thought, with this example as a guide, we should be able to work out the spectral radius of any complete $k$-partite graph.  We expect the Perron-Frobenius eigenvector to be a "block vector" of $k$ blocks, where each block is a constant vector whose length is the size of the corresponding part of the graph.  <s>I can't do this off the top of my head, but it doesn't sound hard.</s>  I don't see a formula, but this approach reduces the problem to finding the eigenvalues of a $k\times k$ matrix.  In the instant case, we would just have to show that the largest eigenvalue of $$
\pmatrix{
0&4&12\\
4&0&12\\
4&4&0
} \text { and }
\pmatrix{
0&9&9\\
2&0&9\\
2&9&0}
$$
are both $12$.